# ArrayList with objects

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList filled with objects "Project" called projectsCurrent. Each project has its name, state, manDays etc.

I wanna iterate through this list and on each project check `if (manDaysDone >= manDays)`. If it does, than the project is done and I wanna change its state, remove it from the list and add it to another one (`projectsDone`).

When I try to use Iterator to achieve my goal, it seems like the link to the current project is lost inside the iteration, for example, in this code, an `NoSuchElementException` is raised inside the if condition:

```
Iterator<Project> i = projectsCurrent.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()){
    if (i.next().getManDaysDone() >= i.next().getManDays()){
        i.next().setState(ProjectState.DONE);
    } 
}
```

Just to make clear what I want to achieve. The following `for` loop does the job, but of course later I get the `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
for (Project currentProject : projectsCurrent){
    if (currentProject.getManDaysDone() >= currentProject.getManDays()) {
        currentProject.setState(ProjectState.DONE);
        projectsDone.add(currentProject);
        this.budget += currentProject.getPrice();
        projectsCurrent.remove(currentProject);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you adding `currentproject`  just update that object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one note. You're planning to remove items randomly from the list. `ArrayList` implementation is not good for it. You should use `LinkedList` instead.

To correctly remove element from the `List`, you have to manually get `Iterator` and call `it.remove()` to remove it. (When you try to remove using within `for(...)`, you get concurrent modification exception, because you have to use **same** iterator to iterate and to remove).

```
List<Project> projects = new LinkedList<>();
Iterator<Project> it = projects.iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String project = it.next();

    if (project.getManDaysDone() >= project.getManDays()) {
        project.setState(ProjectState.DONE);
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You call `next` three times in the loop. Each `next` will move the iterator forward. I guess that causes the `NoSuchElementException`

```
  while (i.hasNext()){
        Project project = i.next();
        if (project.getManDaysDone() >= project.getManDays()){
            project.setState(ProjectState.DONE);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: The same error is raised on the line where Im assigning the value of i.next() to project. When I run the code in debugger I can see that i.next() has the value of the right object at that time.

Comment: I started the whole project again it works now, there must had been a mistake somewhere else. Thank you very much.